# Problem: When to hide a product in sub category from showing in the main category?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

thanks in advance. This issue has been bugging me.

On my website, I have a **main category** called **'Lighting'** and one **subcategory** within it called **'accessories'** shown below: 
[image: Main & Sub Cat]

When on the main category page 'Lighting', products from the sub category 'Accessories' are shown. How do I NOT show them here?

It is an issue because when entering the 'Lighting' landing page you expect to see lights and not accessories, but you would still expect 'Accessories' to feature as a sub category within 'Lighting' - part of the website navigation. 
This I expect is having a negative effect on visitors.

It is worth mentioning that in the backend for manage products I have deselected the products I do not want showing up in the 'lighting' main category and kept them within the 'accessories' sub category. Yet they still show up on the main cat landing page.

I want them removed from the main CAT but kept in the sub CAT. Why does this not work? It seems like it should.

Thank you in advance,

Not found an answer elsewhere but I am sure many people experience the same.

David

Answer (score 0):

It's not an **issue** is a **feature**, go to `admin->catalog->manage categories->select your sub category(accessories)->display Settings->Is Anchor->No->Save`.

> **Is Anchor** consists to enable products from children categories to be **visible** in parent category. it has also have bigger
>   purpose to present all children categories in
>   layer navigation for that parent category.